# How to close Facebook popup after authentication?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I have a Rails 3.2.7 application with the `ominiauth-facebook` gem and I am already authenticating the user but when the callback gets activated, a.k.a, when the user is sent back to my web app I was trying to close the popup this way:

```
if (window.opener !== null) {
  window.opener.location = "/";
  window.opener.close();
}
```

and I've tried

```
if (window.opener !== null) {
  window.opener.location = "/";
  window.close();
}
```

Both don't behave well. The problem with them is that, for example, if I send you a link to my app via Gmail, your Gmail window will get closed after my app is opened in another window/tab.

I really want to make the authentication "popup-ish" in my app and I'm pretty sure it is possible because I've seen this in other sites.

So I wanna a solution that won't annoy the user closing his opener window and also wanna close the FB popup window when the authentication is done.

I appreciate any help you can give me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK, it will take care of handling it all for you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/